# MongoDB mLab mongoose Node.js driver - connection timeout after a period of idle time?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a simple **Node.js** that uses **mongoose** to connect with **Mongo** database hosted on **mLab**.

Everything seems working just fine: adding new records, querying for existing stuff.

Only sometimes, after some period of inactivity, when I look at the console I see the following:

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connection timeout
    at Db.<anonymous> (___PATH___/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/connection.js:168:17)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Db.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Server.listener (___PATH___/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:1786:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Server.<anonymous> (___PATH___/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:274:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Pool.<anonymous> (___PATH___/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:334:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (___PATH___/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:270:12)
    at Connection.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:191:7)
```

Right now it doesn't matter that much to me - I can always restart the app. I'm worried that in production it will cause a lot of headaches so I preemptively ask what's the issue here?

Note that initially everything is working fine, it after some time when I get `Error: connection timeout`

Comment: even I am facing same issue , any break through ?

Comment: @CleanCrispCode nudged the support... I wasn't working on this piece of code in the past couple of days.

Comment: did you get any solution? @MichalStefanow

Comment: *I suspect it might be my computer going to sleep.* - *Yes, it's likely that when your computer goes to sleep it closes the connection sockets it has open to your mLab database.* - * I would recommend that you start testing your application from the same cloud datacenter as your mLab database. This way your application is not impacted by whether or not your computer is active, and you'll also benefit from both a latency and security perspective: http://docs.mlab.com/security/#network* - NO IDEA... Didn't test thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

*Sample Connection code for Mongo-Node using Mongoose*

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');

const options = {
    useMongoClient: true,
    reconnectTries: 5000,
    reconnectInterval: 0,
    socketTimeoutMS: 100000,
    connectTimeoutMS: 100000
  }

mongoose.connect(mongodb://........, options);
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', function (error) {
  console.log('Error while connecting to mongodb database:', error);
});

db.once('open', function () {
  console.log('Successfully connected to mongodb database');
});

db.on('disconnected', function () {
  //Reconnect on timeout
  mongoose.connect(mongodb://........, options);
  db = mongoose.connection;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. it seems that there is fluctuation in your internet connection. Maybe this is the reason of connection timeout.
2. you can handle it by setting the timeout.

As below :

```
var timeout = require('connect-timeout');
app.use(timeout('5s'));`
```

in your `app.js` file

Comment: *"fluctuation in your internet connection"* - could it be computer going to sleep? I've just returned from a walk and very same stuff: ```Error: connection timeout```

Comment: The high availability checks that are supposed to help Mongoose to connect to the secondary after a failover weren't running correctly. Due to some kind of race condition, if the server takes a while to boot up after initializing the Mongoose connection, the callback to start the checks fails in mongodb-core.

What I found by ended up doing is moving the Mongoose connection as late into the server startup process as possible. It used to be before a pretty large file minification task, which was likely the problem.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @ShekharTyagi Would you mind elaborating on your solution by showing some sample code?  Thanks.

Comment: hi @user6860460 , you can check the example on the website, please have a look.
https://github.com/expressjs/timeout

Answer (score 0):

**Replace your mongoose connection setting by this code:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

/* 
 * Mongoose by default sets the auto_reconnect option to true.
 * We recommend setting socket options at both the server and replica set level.
 * We recommend a 30 second connection timeout because it allows for 
 * plenty of time in most operating environments.
 */
var options = { server: { socketOptions: { keepAlive: 300000, connectTimeoutMS: 30000 } }, 
                replset: { socketOptions: { keepAlive: 300000, connectTimeoutMS : 30000 } } };       

var mongodbUri = 'mongodb://user:pass@host:port/db';

mongoose.connect(mongodbUri, options);
var conn = mongoose.connection;             

conn.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));  

conn.once('open', function() {
  // Wait for the database connection to establish, then start the app.                         
});
```

Comment: @KrishnanKantSharma:  When you start the app with ```var app = express()``` in the ```conn.once('open', function()``` section, how do you export ```app``` for use in other statements (such as ```app.use```) later in the code?  Without exporting ```app```, I get a ```ReferenceErrorL: app is not defined``` error when trying to start the express app.

Comment: @user6860460 export your express app like as `module.exports = app`. Then use it in your MongoDB connection file like as:

`const app = require("../your express app file path");

app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 8080 );

const server =  app.listen(app.get("port"), function() {
 console.log("Express server listening on port " + server.address().port);
});`